# Grafana clone alerts

Tags: grafana-alerts

Grafana 9.2.2 works with created alerts. I need to run exactly the same Grafana with notifications in a docker container on any other host. Do this without manually creating alerts.

I can't find JSON file with alert variables.

Answer (score 0):

The alerts config stored inside the Grafana DB, not in any config file, so its not easy migration.

You can take out the DB dump of Grafana from the container where alerts are configured and restore the DB in new Grafana container.

Reference : https://grafana.com/blog/2020/01/13/how-to-migrate-your-configuration-database/

One more option is to create alerts using [file Provisioning](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/alerting/set-up/provision-alerting-resources/file-provisioning/) instead of UI so that the YAML can be applied to any cluster.